# How can I install and enable the Tonez_V2 plugin for LMMS?

Tags: plugins, lmms

[Tonez](https://github.com/retornz/ToneZ), an open source audio plugin built with the cross-platform [cabbage](https://cabbageaudio.com/), appears to be unrecognized by LMMS in Ubuntu 23.10.

[Version 2.0.0](https://www.retornz.com/ld/ToneZ_V2-x64-2.0.0_Linux.zip) of Tonez for Linux includes the following instructions:

> Here are the steps to install it :
>
> 1. Make your to have csound v6 installed on your computer
> 2. Copy the "Retornz" folder inside your $HOME directory
> 3. Finally copy the .so and/or .vst3 plugin where your host can find
>    it

csound version 6 and LMMS are installed via the APT repos:

```
sudo apt install lmms csound csladspa
```

And I tried copying the `.so` file at the root of the unzipped folder:

```
unzip ToneZ_V2-x64-2.0.0_Linux.zip
cd ToneZ_V2-x64-2.0.0/

sudo cp ToneZ_V2.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lmms/ladspa/
```

(Once I get this working, I plan on trying other paths, like my home directory or `/usr/local/`, but am happy to get this to work in any way).

In addition to following step 2, I tried installing the `.so` file to my home directory:

```
cp -a Retornz/ ~
cp ToneZ_V2.so ~/Documents/lmms/plugins/ladspa/
```

---

However none of these steps (then relaunching LMMS) cause the plugin to appear where I'm checking: the "Instrument Plugins" button at the top of the left side of the window, and under the "Tools -> LADSPA Plugin Browser" menus.

Answer (score 1):

I have it working on Linux Mint 21.3 (a Ubuntu derivative) but with a few caveats regarding button functionality. Here is how I installed as per the instructions from ToneZ's README (had to change some things):

> 1. Make sure to have csound v6 installed on your computer

I built csound from source following the instructions [here](https://github.com/csound/csound/blob/develop/BUILD.md#debian) for Ubuntu/Debian. Step 1 of the build instructions reads:

> Edit, as root, /etc/apt/sources.list and ensure that each line
> beginning with deb has another line below it that is identical except
> that deb is replaced with deb-src. Then run sudo apt-get update.

However my `sources.list` in Mint is empty. I figured out you have to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` instead.

Then follow the rest of the instructions to build csound v6.

Now back to the ToneZ README instructions:

> 2. Copy the "Retornz" folder inside your $HOME directory

Easy enough.

> 3. Finally copy the .so and/or .vst3 plugin where your host can find
>    it

For me on Mint, I had to copy the `ToneZ_V2.vst3` directory to my `/lib/vst3/` directory and then copy the `ToneZ_V2.so` file to `/lib/lxvst/` directory.

Everything sounds great but for some reason, the "Open", "Folder", and "Save" buttons seem to do nothing for me, so I have to cycle through the presets manually. If anyone knows how to fix that, feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial solution:** LMMS `1.3.0-alpha` or later is required for running LV2 plugins, so I compiled LMMS from source. This alpha version of LMMS doesn't show original plugin interfaces, but provides an array of knobs. Later versions might support original UIs.

```
sudo apt build-dep lmms
sudo apt install libqt5x11extras5-dev libsndfile1-dev libwine-dev lv2-dev \
                 lv2-c++-tools lilv-utils liblilv-dev libsuil-dev
```

Some of these packages are needed, and some enable LV2 and VST systems, so install them before you compile LMMS. (Confirm by checking cmake command output).

Follow the build instructions in `INSTALL.txt` from the [LMMS git repo](https://github.com/LMMS/lmms).

I haven't found a way to add modules in my home directory, but LMMS does recognize the Helm plugin (another advanced synth, but in Ubuntu repos) installed to the system via: `sudo apt install helm`. I haven't tested placing libraries in `/usr/local/lib/lv2/`.

To use an LV2 synth in the compiled version of LMMS, open the "Instruments Plugins" icon in the left pane, then scroll down, and expand the "LV2" submenu below. Right click on the instrument you want to use, then select "Send Instrument to Track".